# Android - Cut audio file for 2 seconds in beginning and 1 second in end

Tags: android, audio, inputstream

I require to cut my 1 audio sample to another which have no data of staring of 2 seconds and 1 second of last. Currently I am trying following code , but its not get cut properly.

Header is of 44 bytes , 2 second is of 176400  and 1 sec 88200

```
 private void copyWaveFileForAlgo(String inFilename, String outFilename) {
        Log.v("copyWaveFile ", "---------copyWaveFile---------");
        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        long totalAudioLen = 0;
        long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
        long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
        int channels = 1;
        long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels / 8;

       byte[] tmpdata = new byte[88200];
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;



        int lenth = 0;
        Log.v("data ", "----totalDataLen-----"+totalDataLen+"---------"+tmpdata.length);
        long dataToCopy = totalDataLen - 88200;
        long dataLenthTransfered = 0;
        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen, longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);
         long skippedB = 0;
          lenth = in.read(tmpdata);

             while (lenth != -1)
            {

                if (skippedB <176400)
                {
                    skippedB+= in.skip(88200);
                 Log.v("skippedB ", "----skippedB-----"+skippedB+"---------");
                }else
                {
                    if(dataLenthTransfered < dataToCopy)
                    {Log.v("dataLenth ", "----elseee-----"+dataLenthTransfered+"-----dataToCopy----"+dataToCopy);
                     out.write(tmpdata);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Log.v("dataLenthTransfered ", "----dataLenthTransfered-----"+dataLenthTransfered+"----dataToCopy-----"+dataToCopy);
                    }

                }
                dataLenthTransfered+=lenth;
                  lenth = in.read(tmpdata);
            }
in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Vyoma

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you mean by _"its not get cut properly"_.

Comment: Rather then 2 seconds its cutting more from beginning.. & not able to get total length while mentioning on header

Comment: While you're skipping data you're also calling `read`. Either skip or read; don't do both.